# Issue with Submit Transaction

Tags: horizon, java-sdk

Am using Java SDK and Horizon Testnet.

Issue is when i submit a transaction using `server.submitTransaction` method i get following exception, please let me know if you need any more information

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your problem is related to the SSL protocol versions mismatch. Stellar official Testnet Horizon instance has only `TLSv1.2` enabled, while `TLSv1.1`, `TLSv1.0`, `SSLv3`, `SSLv2` are disabled (you can check it [here](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/)).

Consider switching to Java 8, they made `TLSv1.2` the default SSL protocol starting with Java 8, it was `TLSv1.0` in Java 7. Or you can use `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` flag to specify the protocol explicitly.

Check additional info regarding Java SSL support [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am using Java 7 in the code when i have set System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2"); which fixed most of the stellar related issues in my code except the SubmitTransaction

Comment: It sounds like the answer helped you and might even have solved your issue. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and if an answer solves your issue, click the ✓